# Why the icon/image with my toplink is not showing up?

Tags: header

OK i added a new top link to my header on homepage  named 'Cash-On-Delivery'. Now i want to add an icon just before this link-its a small cart icon in .png format.

I added the COD top link by adding this code to customer.xml :
(The customer.xml is located in app/design/frontEnd/base/default/layout/customer.xml)

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
<label>Cash-On-Deliverya</label>
<url>terms</url>
<title></title>
<prepare>true</prepare>
<urlParams></urlParams>
<position>2</position>
<liParams/>
 <aParams>
 <class>cod</class>
</aParams>
<beforeText></beforeText>
<afterText></afterText>
</action>
</reference>
</default>
```

I then defined my 'cod' class in styles.css in skin/frontend/Des_Pckg/themeName/default/css/styles.css
here it is:

```
.cod {
background: url(../images/cod-icon.png) no-repeat top left;
padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
```

}

i also tried:

```
li.cod {
background: url(../images/cod-icon.png) no-repeat top left;
padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
```

}

The icon cod-icon.png is placed in:
skin/frontend/ThemeName/deafult/images.

Am I doing it the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<aParams>
 <class>cod</class>
</aParams>
```

try `<aParams> class="cod"</aParams>`
`aParams` does not support subtags. it does not interpret the subtags you add as an array.

Comment: Its still not working.

Comment: Its working now.i placed my css in a wrong file.Thanks a million :)